# AWS signed request ceased - IAM thing?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I've searched the questions but cant find a specific on this. Sorry if it's been answered.

I built my own site plugin some time back that searches Amazon for items based on the content of a wordpress post. This required an AWS signed request to commence the search and return the values.

However three weeks or so ago, this code has summarily stopped working. I haven't changed a line of code across the entire site, not least in the scripts concerning this small plugin.

It leads me to think that my AWS signed request is failing at the first hurdle - as the rest of the php isnt even commencing.

I've checked AWS and havent seen any notifications about changes or deprecations. My billing is functional and up to date.

One thing I do have a notice for is to change my IAM settings to bring them up to date. I dont fully understand these and will have to read in and make the necessary amendments.

One of those is to change the root key. That, as far as I remember, is what my AWS signed request is partly based on.

Before I go meddling in an area I dont yet fully grasp: is it possible that it could be these IAM settings needing updated that has caused my php scripts commencing with an AWS Signed Request to stop working?

I am really grateful for your advice: this is all a bit of an ache to a novice.

Comment: *"It leads me to think that my AWS signed request is failing at the first hurdle - as the rest of the php isnt even commencing."*  It sounds like you are speculating, which will not take you very far in troubleshooting, because incorrect assumptions are easier to make than correct ones.  Read the logs.  Pinpoint the error.  If your plugin doesn't write enough diagnostic logging, then add some.  *"One thing I do have a notice for is to change my IAM settings to bring them up to date."*  Please don't paraphrase.  What, exactly, did this notice say?

Comment: Thanks Michael. Sorry, Im simply not developed enough as a coder to know what logs to look for - I am indeed speculating. 

My IAM messages are as follows:

- Delete your root access keys
- Activate MFA on your root account
- Create individual IAM users (DONE)
- Use groups to assign permissions
- Apply an IAM password policy

Im wondering are these linked to an AWS root key for the signed request? Or is IAM totally seperate from all of that, as a system?

Comment: That may be related.  Which AWS service are you contacting that *"searches Amazon for items based on the content"*?  Is that the Product Advertising API?  It appears that this service can be linked to your AWS account though isn't exactly an AWS service in the strictest sense... but if you were using your AWS root credentials and then you removed them, that would explain the failure.  Possibly helpful: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ViewingCredentials.html